# Are the iterates of this function bounded?

Tags: limits, fractals, complex-dynamics

I have the function $f(z) = \sqrt z + C.$

For the value of $C = i$ (complex number), would the iterates be bounded or not?

Iterating from $z = 0: f(0) = i, f(i) = \sqrt i + i$ and it goes on, getting more difficult to read as it progresses.

Comment: Given the two questions you've asked, it appears that you've embarked on the study of complex dynamics. I strongly recommend that you use a computational tool.  Examining the decimal approximations of iterates of this function programmatically, it certainly appears that the iterates converge.  In fact, they converge to the unique, attractive fixed point of the function.